# Need help with this integral $\int_0^{\pi/2}{dx\over{4+9\cos^2x}}$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to solve this integral - 
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}{dx\over{4+9\cos^2x}}$$

I've started by dividing numerator and denominator by $\cos^2x$

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}{{dx\over{\cos^2x}}\over{{4+9\cos^2x}\over{\cos^2x}}}$$

which gives me

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}{{\sec^2x}{dx}\over{4{\sec^2x}+9}}$$

I cant go any further. Can someone help / point me in the right direction please?

Comment: You don't solve integrals, you evaluate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}{{\sec^2x}\;{dx}\over{4{\sec^2x}+9}}=\int_0^{\pi/2}{{\sec^2x}\;{dx}\over{4{(1+\tan^2x)}+9}}$$

Now substitute $\tan x =t$ which gives $\sec^2x\; dx=dt$ and thus the integral becomes $$\int_0^{\infty}{{dt}\over{4{(1+t^2)}+9}}=\int_0^{\infty}{{dt}\over{4{t^2}+13}}$$ which is standard integral.

Comment: Does "\sec" work in $\TeX$?

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the substitution $u = \tan(x/2)$, some algebraic manipulation will give you a rational function in $u$ as an integrand. From there you can use partial fractions.

Answer (score 0):

## Hint

Calculate

1. $d(\tan{x})=$
2. $1+\tan^2{x}=$

Answer (score 0):

You can work as following:

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2}{dx\over{4+9cos^2x}}
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}{{sec^2x}{dx}\over{4{sec^2x}+9}}\\
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}{{d\tan x}\over{4{\tan^2x}+13}}
\end{align*}$$

Set $y=\tan x$, you can get

$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi/2}{{d\tan x}\over{4{\tan^2x}+13}}
&=\int_{0}^{+\infty}{{dy}\over{13+4y^{2}}}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{13}}\arctan\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}y|_{0}^{+\infty}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{4\sqrt{13}}
\end{align*}$$